# Android Custom Single Choice List

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a custom listView with the following layout, and I want it to behave like a normal SingleChoiceListView. Although I have the listview set for Single_Choice_Mode, when i click, the radio button does not get selected. What am I doing wrong?
The xml layout for a single row is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:gravity="center_vertical"
          android:minHeight="?listPreferredItemHeightSmall"
          android:orientation="horizontal"
          android:clickable="true"
          android:focusable="true"
          android:paddingLeft="16dip"
          android:paddingRight="12dip" >
    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:orientation="vertical" >
        <TextView
                android:id="@android:id/text1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ellipsize="marquee"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|left"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="?textColorAlertDialogListItem" />
        <TextView
                android:id="@android:id/text2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ellipsize="marquee"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|left"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:textColor="?textColorAlertDialogListItem" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/preco"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:ellipsize="marquee"
            android:gravity="fill"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textColor="@color/appgreen" />
    <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio"
            android:layout_width="35dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:paddingRight="12dip" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Can you post the XML with the <ListView> too?

Comment: <ListView
            android:id="@+id/list"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
            android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
            />

Answer (score 0):

I think when you click on an item in your listview - listview handle this click before your checkbox. You can override onItemClickListener on listView and in it find your checkbox by findViewId in your custom layout and then programatically change status of the checkbox.

Comment: I tried to copy the structure of the android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2_single_choice, and even added the android:duplicateParentState="true" to the radio button, but still, it is not checked.

Answer (score 0):

Use this in stead of `android.r.layout.simple_list_item_single_choice`. Create your own `r.layout.my_single_choice.xml`

```
<CheckedTextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:checkMark="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorSingle"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:padding="5dip"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:textStyle="bold" >
</CheckedTextView>
```

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm a bit late, but I just ran to the same issue and found a solution here (translated):
https://extra--vision-blogspot-com.translate.goog/2016/07/android-single-choice-listview.html?_x_tr_sl=auto&_x_tr_tl=en&_x_tr_hl=en-US&_x_tr_pto=nui

I used a custom adapter that holds the position of the selected item, like the one in this example:

```
public final class SingleChoiceAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
    private static final String[] FRUITS = {
        "Apple", "Banana", "Lemon", "Orange", "Grape"
    };
    private final LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private int mSelectedIndex = -1;
    SingleChoiceAdapter(Context context) {
        super(context, 0);
        addAll(FRUITS);
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = convertView;
        if (view == null) {
            view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_layout, parent, false);
        }
    
        TextView textView       = (TextView)    view.findViewById(R.id.text_view);
        RadioButton radioButton = (RadioButton) view.findViewById(R.id.radio_button);
        String fruit = getItem(position);
        textView.setText(fruit);
        radioButton.setChecked(position == mSelectedIndex);
        return view;
    }
    void setSelectedIndex(int index) {
        mSelectedIndex = index;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

and then implemented a `setOnItemClicklistener` on the list view, like this example:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ListView listView = new ListView(this);
        listView.setChoiceMode(AbsListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
        final SingleChoiceAdapter adapter = new SingleChoiceAdapter(this);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new     AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                adapter.setSelectedIndex(i);
            }
        });
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        setContentView(listView);
    }
}
```